# How Can I Make Fotter Better?

Tags: html, css

Hello i've shared my codes on code snippet. I wanna put referanslar and kategoriler section side by side. Any help appreciated. I've tried every way but i could not fix it. Footer is too big also it does not seem good. How can i put referanslar and kategoriler section side by side? Thanks already. I've searched from google and asked many people but still could not figure it out.

```css
.site-footer {
  background-color: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #eeafdd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
  display: block
}

.footer-links a {
  color: #ffffff
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block
}

.site-footer .social-icons {
  text-align: right
}

.site-footer .social-icons a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #33353d
}

.copyright-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .site-footer [class^=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .site-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,
  .site-footer .social-icons {
    text-align: center
  }
}

.social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}

.social-icons li.title {
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #96a2b2;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px
}

.social-icons a {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  color: #818a91;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear
}

.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #060708
}

.social-icons.size-sm a {
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 14px
}

.social-icons a.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #ff0606
}

.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced
}

.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #0f86fd
}

.social-icons a.dribbble:hover {
  background-color: #e86969
}

@media (max-width:7px) {
  .social-icons li.title {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: 600
  }
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 ">
        <h6>Kategoriler</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
          <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
          <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
          <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3  ">
        <h6>Referans Linkleri</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="https://www.adu.edu.tr/" target="_blank"> Adnan Menderes Üniversitesi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hakanguleryuz.com.tr/" target="_blank">Hakan Güleryüz</a></li>
          <li><a href="elcinerbil.com.tr" target="_blank">Elçin Erbil</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://afranurkalafat.com.tr/" target="_blank">Afra Nur Kalafat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://eylulidilozeren.com/" target="_blank">Eylül İdil Özeren</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://busramelekuzdu.com.tr/" target="_blank">Büşra Melek Uzdu</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/sitemap.xml" target="_blank">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved by
          <a href="#">Buse Nur Çetin</a>.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><a class="Github" href="https://github.com/busenurcetin" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="dribbble" href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-safari"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/busenur-%C3%A7etin-349b05253/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a flexbox for the `row` class. Documentation added in CSS code.

```css
/* Added */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Adjust calculations width/heigth of elements */
}

.site-footer > .container > .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* Devides the space around the columns */
}
/* ------------------------ */

.site-footer {
  background-color: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #eeafdd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
  display: block
}

.footer-links a {
  color: #ffffff
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block
}

.site-footer .social-icons {
  text-align: right
}

.site-footer .social-icons a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #33353d
}

.copyright-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .site-footer [class^=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .site-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,
  .site-footer .social-icons {
    text-align: center
  }
}

.social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}

.social-icons li.title {
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #96a2b2;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px
}

.social-icons a {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  color: #818a91;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear
}

.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #060708
}

.social-icons.size-sm a {
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 14px
}

.social-icons a.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #ff0606
}

.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced
}

.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #0f86fd
}

.social-icons a.dribbble:hover {
  background-color: #e86969
}

@media (max-width:7px) {
  .social-icons li.title {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: 600
  }
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 ">
        <h6>Kategoriler</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
          <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
          <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
          <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3  ">
        <h6>Referans Linkleri</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="https://www.adu.edu.tr/" target="_blank"> Adnan Menderes Üniversitesi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hakanguleryuz.com.tr/" target="_blank">Hakan Güleryüz</a></li>
          <li><a href="elcinerbil.com.tr" target="_blank">Elçin Erbil</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://afranurkalafat.com.tr/" target="_blank">Afra Nur Kalafat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://eylulidilozeren.com/" target="_blank">Eylül İdil Özeren</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://busramelekuzdu.com.tr/" target="_blank">Büşra Melek Uzdu</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/sitemap.xml" target="_blank">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved by
          <a href="#">Buse Nur Çetin</a>.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><a class="Github" href="https://github.com/busenurcetin" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="dribbble" href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-safari"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/busenur-%C3%A7etin-349b05253/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.row {
  display:flex;
}  
.row > div {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```css
.row {
display:flex;
}  
.row > div {
flex: 1 1;
}  
.site-footer {
  background-color: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #eeafdd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
  display: block
}

.footer-links a {
  color: #ffffff
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block
}

.site-footer .social-icons {
  text-align: right
}

.site-footer .social-icons a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #33353d
}

.copyright-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .site-footer [class^=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .site-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,
  .site-footer .social-icons {
    text-align: center
  }
}

.social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}

.social-icons li.title {
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #96a2b2;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px
}

.social-icons a {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  color: #818a91;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear
}

.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #060708
}

.social-icons.size-sm a {
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 14px
}

.social-icons a.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #ff0606
}

.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced
}

.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #0f86fd
}

.social-icons a.dribbble:hover {
  background-color: #e86969
}

@media (max-width:7px) {
  .social-icons li.title {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: 600
  }
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 ">
        <h6>Kategoriler</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
          <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
          <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
          <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3  ">
        <h6>Referans Linkleri</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="https://www.adu.edu.tr/" target="_blank"> Adnan Menderes Üniversitesi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hakanguleryuz.com.tr/" target="_blank">Hakan Güleryüz</a></li>
          <li><a href="elcinerbil.com.tr" target="_blank">Elçin Erbil</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://afranurkalafat.com.tr/" target="_blank">Afra Nur Kalafat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://eylulidilozeren.com/" target="_blank">Eylül İdil Özeren</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://busramelekuzdu.com.tr/" target="_blank">Büşra Melek Uzdu</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/sitemap.xml" target="_blank">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved by
          <a href="#">Buse Nur Çetin</a>.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><a class="Github" href="https://github.com/busenurcetin" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="dribbble" href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-safari"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/busenur-%C3%A7etin-349b05253/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```